# Add a custom button in related products magento 2

Tags: magento2

[image]

I am trying to add a custom button or href link in related products.

[image]

Comment: Ok so where you want to added those things into that place?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya now the question is updated, please check.

Comment: tell me the path of your phtml which currently call for the above Related product block.

Comment: Custom\Module\view\frontend\templates\product\list\items.phtml

Comment: I post answer, please check that one.

Comment: did you get your answer now, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create **catalog_product_view.xml** in your module file and set custom block for the related products. Also, need to set custom phtml file path for the add button.

> **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-right" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
      <referenceContainer name="content.aside">
        <!-- For Related Product -->
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ProductList\Related" name="catalog.product.related" template="Vendor_Module::product/list/items.phtml">
            <arguments>
               <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">related</argument>
               <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\Listing\PreparePostData</argument>
            </arguments>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="related.product.addto" as="addto">
               <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                  name="related.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                  template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </block>
        <!-- For Upsell Product -->
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell" name="product.info.upsell" template="Vendor_Module::product/list/items.phtml">
            <arguments>
               <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">upsell</argument>
               <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\Listing\PreparePostData</argument>
            </arguments>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="upsell.product.addto" as="addto">
               <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                  name="upsell.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                  template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </block>
      </referenceContainer>
   </body>
</page>
```

After, you need to create **items.phtml** to add custom button.

> **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml**

```
$type = $block->getType();
if($type == 'related')
{
    // Add your button code.
}
```

Now, Just clean cache and check it.

Answer (score 0):

Open this file :

```
Custom\Module\view\frontend\templates\product\list\items.phtml
```

Now at the place where you want to show that button, do this code.

```
$type = $block->getType();
if($type == 'related')
{
    //PUT your custom button code here;
}
```

So this thnigs show button only on related product block.

Comment: Is only change in 
Custom\Module\view\frontend\templates\product\list\items.phtml 

or any another file i have to change???

Comment: This is the only change you need to do.

Comment: Then nothing reflecting on change on items.phtml . checked in fresh magento 2.4.3

Comment: First confirm the file into which you are doing coding is called and then also check the if part executed properly.

Answer (score -1):

in your `Custom\Module\etc\di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related" type="Custom\Module\Block\Product\ProductList\Related" />
</config>
```

in `Custom\Module\Block\Product\ProductList\Related.php`

```
class Related extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('Custom_Module::product/list/items.phtml');
    }
}
```

now copy all content from

`Magento\Catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list\items.phtml`

To

`Custom\Module\view\frontend\templates\product\list\items.phtml`

and add your required button..Flush Cache and see results

Comment: the button is not reflecting. flow all steps above.

Comment: enable template hinting and check is template overriding fine  https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-enable-template-path-hints-magento-2.html

Answer (score -1):

Simple you go to you following path and override **`items.phtml`** in your theme.

**`module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list\items.phtml`**

Override your theme like :-

**`Vendor_name\Theme_Name\Magento_Catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list\items.phtml`**

And Add Some code in your **`items.phtml`** file.

```
<strong class="newbtn"><a class="product-item-link" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Custom Button')) ?>" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl($_item)) ?>">
                                                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Custom Button')) ?></span>
                                            </strong>
```

And Add some css :-

```
<style type="text/css">
                .newbtn {
                    display: block;
                    width: 115px;
                    height: 25px;
                    background: black;
                    padding: 10px;
                    text-align: center;
                    border-radius: 5px;
                    color: white;
                }
            </style>
```

After change your run below commnad :-

```
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

And check **`OutPut :-`**

[image]

**`NOTE:-`** This code href link is get product link. And you want to other link remove this code **`<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl($_item)) ?>`** and your static url like :- **`href="http://127.0.0.1/mage224/test.html"`**.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: the button is not reflecting. flow all steps above

Comment: first your try core file change and core file is working after your override .

Comment: Hello @vivek It is working or not ?

Comment: No it's not working

Comment: Is only change in Custom\Module\view\frontend\templates\product\list\items.phtml or any another file i have to change???